# Generate blob data from json object in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, blob

How can I create blob data from json object ?

I tried few approaches as shown below but front-end always receives empty blob.

---

**Approach: 1**

```
const buffer = require("buffer"); 

const myJsonFileData = { "id": 1, "name":"abc"};

const str = JSON.stringify(myJsonFileData );

const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);

const blobForJsonFile = new buffer.Blob([bytes], {
    type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
});


return res.send({filename:'xxx.json', blob: blobForJsonFile });
```

But front-end always receives

```
blob: {}
filename: "xxx.json"
```

If I get proper blob data, at FE, I want create `xxx.json` file.

---

**Approach: 2**

```
const Blob = require("buffer").Blob;

const myJsonFileData = { "id": 1, "name":"abc"};

const blob1 = new Blob([JSON.stringify(myJsonFileData , null, 2)], {
                        type: 'application/json',
              });

return res.send({filename:'xxx.json', blob: blobForJsonFile });
```

But it does give same empty result.

Comment: `const json = JSON.stringify({ a: 1 });
const buffer = Buffer.from(json);
const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
`
maybe like this ?

Comment: Blob is still empty at FE.